# Putty CTRL + a doesnt work on minecraft screen

Tags: putty, minecraft

I have a minecraft server on an other computer and after couple of hours my Putty started acting wierdly when i try to push the server's screen to the background.
I tried ctrl + a d and it was writing this: ^A to the server console.
I can use ctrl + a d if I am not on the minecraft server's screen. Do you have any idea why is it not working? I cannot leave my server running in the background. I can only leave putty with ctrl + C, but that move is closing the server.

Comment: ctrl + a d is used by the linux screen command to detach from it‘s session so i think the problem may be as follows: you had your minecraft server initially be running inside a screen session then you may have stoped minecraft server and left putty (now as there was no command running inside the screen session it got automatically closed on closing putty) then you may have newly started the minecraft server not within a screen session but within the actual Shell which doesn‘t know ctrl + a d.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Ctrl+A+D is just a putty shortcut for typing 'Exit' and sending a return.

If you're not at the commandline, this usually won't have the intended consequences.

The best solution to your problem would be to install tmux (Terminal Multiplexor), this allows you to run programs/scripts/commands (e.g. your minecraft server) in a virtual terminal that continues to run even after you disconnect. As well as having many other useful features.